# Perl regex to obtain coefficient of x and y in equations

Tags: regex, perl

```
<> =~ m/([\+-][0-9]*)x|([\+-][0-9]*)y/;
print "$1, $2";
```

Outputs for various inputs are :

```
3x+1y    ----->, +1
10x-2y   -----> ,  -2
-5x+2y   -----> -5, 
-10x+5y  -----> -10,
```

It's basically behaving randomly, sometimes printing out the co-efficient of x, sometimes y. What is going wrong?

Comment: BTW, what about simply using `(.*)x(.*)y` :)

Comment: @Enissay, nice Idea but it won't match altogether if there is no x or y term(i.e. co-effiecient is zero). :/

Comment: I tougth of that case, but since you didnt mention it, most of the answers I saw here arent considering it... You must add it to you question... edi_allen's solution seems to be working in this case...

Comment: That's why I was using the `|` operator in my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($x, $y);

($x, $y) = <> =~ m/([+-]?[0-9]+(?=[xy]))/g; #assuming x is always the first term

print "$x, $y\n";
```

for more complex expression you can also use this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%number); #use a hash to store coeficcient and variables

my $expression = <>;

while ($expression =~ m/([+-]?[0-9]+)([a-z]+)/ig){
    $number{ $2 } += $1;
}

for my $variable (sort keys %number){
    print "$variable  has coeficcient $number{ $variable }\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an alternation in your pattern: `/(...)x|(...)y/`. Therefore, your pattern matches either something like `-2x` or `+5y`.

Another error is that you require a sign (+ or -) on the x coordinate. You probably want a regex like:

```
/^\s* ([+-]?[0-9]+)x ([+-][0-9]+)y \s*$/x
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using lookaheads so that you don't consume characters and get a cleaner match:

```
^(?=.*?([+-]?[0-9]*)x)(?=.*?([+-]?[0-9]*)y)
```

Compare [your corrected regex](http://regex101.com/r/yN4cY0) (you forgot the `?` to indicate optional sign) with [my suggested regex](http://regex101.com/r/uY9vZ5).

The captured groups are 'all over the place' in the first regex.

It also allows any order of x and y variables, if you want this as bonus :)

Comment: what does `?=.*?` do?

Comment: @udiboy `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead and will look 'ahead' (quite literally) for what's inside the brackets. `a(?=b)` will match an `a` which is followed by b, thus `a` in `ab` will match. If the part inside brackets are not matched, the whole regex will fail to match. Using `(?=.* ... )` is a simple way to check characters than can be far ahead, with many characters in between. E.g. `a(?=.*z)` will match a in `az`, `acz`, `a bcde z`. You can get more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Last `.*?` is a lazy version of `.*` (it matches as little as possible)

Comment: I'm solving a code golf challenge, so this is too long. I am new to these kinds of regexes so I don't know about performance. But edi_allen's version is shorter than mine and works.